# Get Total Comment, Like, Share (PHP Facebook API v2.4)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've read facebook documentation about [comment](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/object/comments) and [like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/object/likes) but still confused how to get total comment, like and share from my facebook page feed.

Example how i get comment from my page feed :

```
$facebook = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '',
    'app_secret' => '',
    'default_access_token' => '',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4'
]);

$response = $facebook->get(id/comments?summary=true&fields=from,parent,id,message,created_time&filter=stream')->getGraphEdge();

print_r($response);
```

Response result :

```
[metaData:protected] => Array
    (
        [summary] => Array
            (
                [order] => chronological
                [total_count] => 16
                [can_comment] => 
            )

    )
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0]
        ...
        [15]
    )
```

I know how to get field data, i use `$response->asArray();` but how to get `summary -> total_count` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a helper function `$response->getTotalCount()`.

For any other value, you can use `$response->getMetadata()['summary']['order']`.